# Compression and decompression of png files

Tags: image, png

In my web project, i compressed all PNG images with optipng, with -o3 compression. In modern browsers all is fine, the visualization is not affected and all runs ok.
But, i have an old device with a custom browser engine that have problems with compressed images. So i need to decompress the images, is this possible?
If i open the images with GIMP (for example) i can save the png file again with a 0 compression, i want to ask if there are any "automatic" tool that can do that. With optipng i can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use Zlib to decompress the png compressed with optipng

```
`zlib.decompress(file,level)` //python usage
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, of course its possible.

Just use [IrfanView](http://irfanview.net) and run it in batch mode on all your files.

If you're not using Windows, [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) is probably the best way to go. Just write a script which runs the following command on all your files:

`convert -quality 0 input.png output.png`